# Win10 - Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration. Installation cannot proceed

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition

I am trying to install Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro 15-inch 2019, (macOS Catalina 10.15.5) using Boot Camp. I have two different Win10 ISO files. They both gives me this error:

> Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration.
>   Installation cannot proceed.

I have seen some "fixes" online, but none of them has been working for me. I have tried the following:

1. Re-run Boot Camp Assistant to remove the Windows partition and restore the full Mac HD as a single partition.
2. Run a PRAM reset (restart, while screen is still black, hold down ⌘+Option+P+R and keep them pressed until you hear the startup sound a second time).
3. Open disk utility and repair permissions on the Macintosh HD partition. TWICE.
4. Start Boot Camp Assistant again.

Any tips?

Comment: I though the Boot Configuration is not stored in the Windows partition or any partitions containing the Macintosh HD volume. I thought the Boot Configuration was stored in the EFI partition, when installing Windows to UEFI boot.

Comment: @DavidAnderson What do you mean?

Comment: What macOS version are you on? Add that to your question.

Comment: @Nathan Sure, added now.

Comment: @Koruy: You did not completely remove Windows from the drive. There are also files in the EFI volume that need to be removed. I put the procedure as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove any previous installations of Windows, you would have to remove the `EFI/Boot` and `EFI/Windows` folders from the EFI volume. The `EFI\Windows\Boot` folder contains the Boot Configuration Data (`BCD`) file. You can mount this volume by using the command given below.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
```

You can use the Finder application to move the folders to the trash. Afterwards, empty the trash. You can unmount the EFI volume by using the command given below.

```
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```